# How to use LibTomCrypt with Contiki

Tags: c, ubuntu, cryptography, contiki, libtomcrypt

I am trying to use LibTomCrypt library with Contiki OS but it's not working at all. I get the error: fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD. I have used the following code for computing hash in my client file.

```
 unsigned char* hashSHA1(const char* input, unsigned long inputSize) {
    //Initial
    unsigned char* hashResult = (unsigned char*)malloc(sha1_desc.hashsize);
    //Initialize a state variable for the hash
    hash_state md;
    sha1_init(&md);
    //Process the text - remember you can call process() multiple times
    sha1_process(&md, (const unsigned char*) input, inputSize);
    //Finish the hash calculation
    sha1_done(&md, hashResult);
    // Return the result
    return hashResult;
}
```

and then I call it in send_packet().
I have added the header file

```
`#include <tomcrypt.h>`
```

Now in Makefile, I am not sure how shall I add a path. I have checked a few possible ways, for instance, [Contiki mote type creation error when trying to use libtomcrypt library (rsa public key generation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885964/contiki-mote-type-creation-error-when-trying-to-use-libtomcrypt-library-rsa-pub) and I have added the following lines :

```
    PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += sha1.c
    MODULES += ./libtomcrypt-develop
    PROJECT_LIBRARIES+= $(CONTIKI)/libtomcrypt-develop/libtomcrypt.a
```

(here libtomcrypt-develop is the name of the folder containing LibTomCrypt library)
According to my understanding, I guess there is something wrong in Makefile. Can someone please identify the problem in Makefile?